# Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, homebrew, rbenv

I was doing attempting to do some updates to openssl using homebrew and I somehow managed to break everything. I can't do anything now, this is what I get when I try to do bundle install:

```
$ bundle install
/Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in    `require': dlopen(/Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
in /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/security.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:146:in `install'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/asServer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: SSLv2 is broken, so there's almost no reason for code to have `SSLv2_client_method`. Can you open the Ruby file(s) and comment out references to SSLv2 methods? The underlying cause is `libssl` in `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` was configured with `no-ssl2` (but it should not be a problem in 2014).

Answer (score 289, accepted):

I just fixed a similar issue on my system. You need to rebuild your install of Ruby 2.1.2 and it will re-link against the newly-updated SSL.

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.2
rbenv: /Users/ryan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/f22a6447811a81f3c808d1c2a5ce3b5f5f0955c68c9a749182feb425589e6635
Installing ruby-2.1.2...
Installed ruby-2.1.2 to /Users/ryan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2
```

Comment: This is happening after a fresh install of ruby 1.9.3 via rvm. New Mac and an old code base.  Do I need a different version of openssl?

Comment: @twelve17 The errors are related to not being able to find an SSL library and the OP mentioned that they had recently upgraded their installed version of openssl. I had the same issue with the same upgrade scenario; I suspect the reinstall fixes things by causing Ruby to be built against the upgraded libraries (the old ones cannot be found).

Comment: Just to add to this, if a boxen user comes across this - I could not get rbenv to reinstall using the commands above - so I had to uninstall and reinstall 2.1.2 using rbenv

`rbenv uninstall 2.1.2`
`rbenv install 2.1.2`
`bundle`

Comment: Thank you @RyanDlugosz.  I'm a dummy, missed the openssl reference in the OP, and then assumed you meant your own updated openSSL.  Apologies!

Comment: I can't say for sure but I believe this problem arose after I installed postgresql and the pg gem. I also naively set my ARCHFLAGS env variable as per homebrew's instructions. Again, not sure what if any of that led to this issue but if you did any of those things, this answer may work for you as well.

Comment: After yosemite upgrade, I had this issue.  The above worked, but only after I redirected my gcc.  ````export CC=/usr/bin/gcc```` For more info: [here is the github issue from rbenv that helped](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/610)

Comment: Some may need to run `rbenv rehash` after installing a new ruby [the github](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash)

Comment: After Yosemite, you need to use `clang` or `/usr/bin/gcc` instead of `gcc-4.2` before install ruby. I blogged [how I did](http://goo.gl/bJfqYu) exactly.

Comment: This happened to me after updating all my homebrew formulas. The above reinstall fixed the problem without having to run `rbenv rehash`.

Comment: If you installed rbenv with homebrew you may need to `brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build` as well.

Answer (score 186):

I had a similar issue after upgrading openssl. I use rvm. I started by upgrading rvm.

```
$ rvm get stable
```

I next reinstalled 1.9.3.

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p545
```

After reinstalling, I ran:

```
$ rvm gemset pristine
```

If you see any errors restoring your gemset, your best option will be to empty the gemset and rebuild it.

```
rvm gemset use mygemset
rvm gemset empty mygemset
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

If you have multiple gemsets, you will have to repeat these steps for each one of them.

Comment: This worked for me. rvm kicked off the building of gemset pristine automatically.

Comment: Worked for me on Yosemite, I just ran:

`rvm get stable` and `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0`

Comment: On Yosomite I had a problem installing ruby, since it's not able to find right `gcc` version. I ended up with `CC=/usr/bin/gcc rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p551`

Comment: @MatCarey `rvm get stable` and `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0` worked in Mavericks too. Thanks.

Comment: What worked for me is `rvm get stable` followed by `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p598` (since I was behind a few patch versions). Also, I updated `.ruby-version`, ran `bundle`, and exited my current working directory (`cd ..`) and returned to it (`cd -`) before successfully running `foreman start`.

Comment: Reiterating @Ducain's comment the gemset pristine automatically runs as part of the re-install; you don't have to run it again manually.

Answer (score 17):

Have same issue for 1.9.3-p547, under rvm

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p547
```

Ruby gets re-installed, but fails in setting up a `gemset_pristine` for the application because

```
libv8 version 3.16.14.3 failed
```

which was the reason I got to this point in the first place. Vicious frustration circle...

**update**
Check your platform version. [I have for example Darwin 10.8 and that is not listed here](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8).
So, unless your version of the libv8 gem has a precompiled binary for your platform, it is going to take a long (long-long) time.  Go out for dinner, a movie, chill out...  If enough ask, maybe they'll set up a binary distro...

Comment: I also need support for ruby 1.9.3 and am using `rvm`, `homebrew` and `xcode` v6.1.1 on Yosemite 10.10.2.  I used just `rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p394`; after compiling the new ruby, RVM made the gems pristine, as well with no issues.

Comment: Yes, it is based on the binary distribution.  The link is there to allow one to check first if they will get an immediate response or go off and meditate!

Answer (score 14):

Had the same error and solved it by `brew upgrade openssl`

Comment: did you have to `brew link --force openssl`?

Comment: @kbrock, no I didn't.

Answer (score 7):

### You might be a dork like me, with multiple openssl's

I had the same issue for 2.1.2 and Ryan Dlugosz's excellent answer didn't go far enough. My problem was that I had multiple versions of openssl installed (I think I'd installed through `brew` *and* `git` in previous projects).

I had to delete /opt/local/bin/openssl and then rebuild 2.1.2.

#### Check global rbenv ruby

```
$ rbenv global
2.1.2
```

#### Check openssl

```
$ which -a openssl
/opt/local/bin/openssl
/opt/local/bin/openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

#### Kill off duplicate openssl

```
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/openssl
```

#### Rebuild 2.1.2

```
$ rbenv install -f 2.1.2
Downloading openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/53cb818c3b90e507a8348f4f5eaedb05d8bfe5358aabb508b7263cc670c3e028
Installing openssl-1.0.1g...
Installed openssl-1.0.1g to /Users/globber/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2

Downloading ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/f22a6447811a81f3c808d1c2a5ce3b5f5f0955c68c9a749182feb425589e6635
Installing ruby-2.1.2...
Installed ruby-2.1.2 to /Users/globber/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2
```

Answer (score 5):

#### When did not solve problem at all, I suggest deleting RVM. And reinstall RVM and Rails.

deleting RVM

> [How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

installing RVM, Rail

> $ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
>   $ rvm get stable
>   $ rvm requirements
>   $ rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
>   $ rvm use 2.0.0
>   $ gem update --system 2.0.3
>   $ gem install rails --version 4.0.5

Answer (score 4):

rbenv users:

It helps to make sure that you are using the right version of ruby. If you reinstall rbenv or install a new ruby, change to the ruby version you just installed:

$ rbenv local 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help anyone: I had a newer version of Ruby installed (2.1.2), and in my .ruby-version file I referenced the old one (2.0.0-p353)

Changing my .ruby-version file to 2.1.2 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which occurred after upgrading to ruby 2.2.2.
However, my environment is a little different causing the above solutions to not work.

I'm using:

- OSX Yosemite (10.10.4)
- chruby
- ruby-install
- openssl (installed via homebrew)

The following command(s) resolved this in my situation:

```
> sudo ruby-install -r /opt/rubies ruby 2.2.2 -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
> gem install bundler
> bundler install
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the acceptance answers above, you may have to tell rbenv to use the newly installed version. For example, I had the old version in ~/.rbenv/version, so rbenv was always using the old one. Manually setting the new version in that file (or through the command line) should fix the problem.

```
rbenv install -f 2.1.2
rbenv versions
rbenv global 2.1.2 //sets global version to 2.1.2
```

Comment: and if you have troubles with rbenv not seeing later versions, like somebody I know did... be sure you've updated ruby-build. most likely through brew.