# Error when trying to check Heroku version on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to check to see what version of Heroku I have installed so I can install the heroku tool belt https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ but when I type:

`Heroku --v`

I am getting the following in the terminal:

> BrettMac:~ brettgolding$ heroku --v
>   /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': dlopen(/Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)
>     Referenced from: /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
>     Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>    in /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.33.0/lib/excon.rb:6:in`'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.18/lib/heroku/api.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.18/lib/heroku-api.rb:1:in`'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/client/organizations.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:4:in`'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in`require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in`block in load'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in`load'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/lib/heroku/cli.rb:36:in `start'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/heroku-3.9.6/bin/heroku:17:in`'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
>       from /Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/heroku:23:in`'

I am using OSX and the terminal.

Comment: Thanks smallbutton.com this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with you ruby setup. I think you should try reinstalling ruby like this advises: [Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror)