# Rails rake updating issue - Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake, bundler

I'm attempting (without much success) to run `rake db:migrate` on a rails project, however it returns:

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

I ran `bundle install` and worked fine - installed rake 10.4.2, however when I ran: `rake --version` (for some reason you can't do rake -v  ???) and it shows: `rake, version 0.9.6`

I ran bundle update rake and returned my list of gems and then: `Your bundle is updated!`

Why isn't rake updating? Is there something I'm doing wrong (I'm new to rails btw - so this is probably really simple)

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TL; DR: `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`

So, I had this problem myself. I wanted to know why `rails s` would work yesterday and not today.

First I checked if I was in the correct directory, I was.
Then I re-ran `bundle install` to make sure rake was getting installed. It was, and I was able to see it in my Gemfile.lock
So I figured my gemset might be corrupt (I use RVM). `rvm gemset empty` then `bundle install`

Still, whenever I ran `rails s`, I got this error. `bin/rails s` worked, as well as `bundle exec rails s`. But I don't want a prefix, I want rails to work (It works in other rails projects)

Eventually I tried `gem install rake` and it worked! I recommend adding `-v '10.4.2'` to the command so that you get the correct rake version. Now when I `which rake`, I get the gemset for my project: `"/Users/cm022291/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@project_gemset/bin/rake"`

and when I run `rails s` the server starts successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

That will ensure that the Rake being invoked is the one you've bundled.

Comment: hmmm - I'm getting an error: `rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/TomHill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /Users/TomHill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle` - plus a load of other file paths? - thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you updated OpenSSL since you installed that Ruby?  Looks like an OpenSSL linking failure to me.

Comment: My OpenSSL is: `OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014` - is that ok for executing rake?

Comment: That's not really the question. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror .  You need to rebuild your Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - ran `rbenv install 2.0.0-p247` - then `rake db:migrate` and again, - Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources, so tried `brew install ruby` - and again nothing. `rake --version` still shows 0.9.6. bundle exec rake db:migrate still shows: `LoadError: dlopen` - thanks so much for your help with this btw

Comment: Running `rake db:migrate` is not going to work, per my answer.  You have (or had) two separate problems.  Assuming you've fixed the OpenSSL problem by reinstalling (and rebuilding) Ruby, then run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.  That will invoke the correct Rake.  You should also probably run `rbenv rehash` - https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash - to pick up the updated rake shim.

Comment: Sorry peter - maybe I didn't make myself clear - I tried both `rake db:migrate` as well as `bundle exec rake db:migrate` - neither of which worked... :( - but thanks anyway

Comment: `brew install ruby` won't do anything for the Ruby VM, since you're using rbenv.  You need to rebuild the Ruby.  Try `rbenv install 2.0.0-p598`, set that as your Ruby, run `gem install bundler` and then do bundle.

Comment: Thanks peter - I don't know what happened but it decided to start working once I installed ruby 2.1.0 via rvm - who knows whats going on - thank you for your continued assistance :)