# Upgraded to Yosemite and now ruby libraries are breaking

Tags: ruby, oh-my-zsh, chruby

I upgraded to Yosemite, and now when I try to setup an initial rails app using `rails new <appname>` I am getting an error message:

> /Users/****/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require':
>   dlopen(/Users/*****/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.3.0/openssl.bundle,
>   9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)

I am using homebrew and chruby not RVM and my shell is Oh-my-Zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you compiled Ruby on the old version of Mac OS X, and it depended on the `_SSLv2_client_method` function from OpenSSL.  That function is very old (SSL v2 is an old protocol) so it was probably removed from OpenSSL, and upgrading your operating system probably introduced a new version of OpenSSL without that function.

Anyway, you should just try removing your whole `~/.rubies` folder (or move it to a new place) and starting from scratch, recompiling Ruby according to the [chruby Wiki](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/Ruby).

Here is a related question, which I found by simply Googling for "_SSLv2_client_method ruby mac": [Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror)

Comment: That worked. I guess the only issue I am having now is my bundler wont compile with the bundle install command because zsh wont recognize the command. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Important to note: Do Not delete your usr/.rubies folder. This is the system ruby. I presume David meant Users/userName/.rubies