# Error installing SASS globally on my mac

Tags: css, ruby, macos, sass

I already have SASS installed on my mac: `Sass 3.2.19 (Media Mark)` and `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]` but if I try to update the latest version by either `gem install sass` or `sudo gem install sass` I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/MacBook/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /Users/MacBook/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /Users/MacBook/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/MacBook/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

and I can't figure out what the error means. This is the **[gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/labanino/50687bee0625003745d8/raw/6f73d355bd9b844e88168147e148055d40145b20/sass-error)**. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when installing SASS for the first time. If you have brew, you can try:

```
brew rm openssl
brew cleanup openssl
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby
gem install sass
```