# RVM ruby-1.9.2-p290, Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

while trying to run the bundle install command in my project root directory here the error I am getting

I tried to running brew update but it doesn't help. Any help will be appreciated

> bundle install

```
/Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':     dlopen(/Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle -  /Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:288:in `rescue in request'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:278:in `request'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:257:in `fetch'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:234:in `use_api'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `select'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `remote_specs'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:167:in `fetch_specs'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:216:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:213:in `each'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:213:in `block in index'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:209:in `index'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `resolve'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:82:in `run'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `install'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:76:in `run'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:146:in `install'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.6.0/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/user123/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It's probably worth upgrade from Ruby 1.9.2 if you can manage it. That version is no longer supported on current versions of anything, and as libraries like OpenSSL change, it will be impossible to compile it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25492787).