# Rails server says image not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, server

I've been working on a ruby on rails web app - I'm trying to start a rails server but everytime I type "rails s" into the terminal, an error code appears that says:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin14.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin14.0/digest/sha1.bundle
Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin14.0/digest/sha1.bundle"
```

There is a whole string of extra output that says "from".

Does anyone know how to fix this? I recently updated to Mac El Capitan Beta OS X. I'm not sure if this is the reason (rails s worked yesterday). Since yesterday, I did try to install sass bootstrap - maybe that's the reason?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: This message basically says you're missing some libraries on your computer. Maybe try `sudo apt-get install libcrypto`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an openssl issue. Try:

```
rbenv install 2.1.4
```

Source:
[Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror)