# Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, rvm

When i try to run the server it gives the following error

```
/Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb:17:in `require': dlopen(/Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:74:in `server'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

After looking at the suggestion in this
[Ruby Bundle Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror)
the problem is solved. But after restarting the computer i have to again go through the same procedure that is to do get stable rvm and reinstall the ruby again.

Another thing i noticed was after restarting and opening the terminal it starts with the following error:

```
/Users/brijesh/.rvm/scripts/initialize:48: __rvm_cleanse_variables: function definition file not found
```

I am not sure what is going on and have been stuck in this for this long. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the correct ruby version on your project using your ruby version manager 
 `rvm --default 'ruby-version'` 
Let me know if that works